# Facebook app with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, facebook, iis, facebooktoolkit

I am trying to get my first hello world application on facebook using asp.net with facebook toolkit.

I am hosting my files on www.aspspider.info/jasminm89/ using it as a canvasurl 
and link to my facebook app is http://apps.facebook.com/mytesterapp/

At that location i have: default.html page with the h1 tag with plain text.
When I visit my app on facbook I get message:

> The page cannot be displayed
>
> The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid
>   method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access. Please try the
>   following:
>
> Contact the Web site administrator if you believe that this request
>   should be allowed. Make sure that the Web site address displayed in
>   the address bar of your browser is spelled and formatted correctly.
>   HTTP Error 405 - The HTTP verb used to access this page is not
>   allowed. Internet Information Services (IIS)
>
> Technical Information (for support personnel)
>
> Go to Microsoft Product Support Services and perform a title search
>   for the words HTTP and 405. Open IIS Help, which is accessible in IIS
>   Manager (inetmgr), and search for topics titled Setting Application
>   Mappings, Securing Your Site with Web Site Permissions, and About
>   Custom Error Messages.

here  source code from facebook, where it loads my page:

```
<form action="http://aspspider.info/jasminm89/" 
method="post" target="iframe_canvas" 
id="canvas_iframe_post_4e513da6b75410144827584" 
onsubmit="return Event.__inlineSubmit(this,event)"><input 
type="hidden" autocomplete="off" name="signed_request"
value="xxx....."></form>
```

One point here.
I setup my account on 000webhost.com and by default there is default.php created,
I copy the link to my facebook and it loads the page, it worked as well with plain index.html.

**final**
This error is because with IIS we can't use static html pages to be called in this way
I now upload plain .aspx page with some text and it worked.

Comment: If I go to http://www.aspspider.info/jasminm89/, I get a 404 error. And if I go to http://www.aspspider.info/jasminm89/default.aspx, I get a configuration error. Try it with a simple HTML page so you can see it appear in facebook, then work your way from there (at least you'd know your FB app was set up correctly)

Comment: maybe it is due to aspspider.net, because when i type in my browser
www.aspspider.info/jasminm89/ i get error that page can't be found,
buth when I type http://aspspider.info/jasminm89/ or http://aspspider.info/jasminm89/ page is loaded. I now change the default page to plan html with just h1 tag content.
And now I am on facebook geting message: "The page cannot be displayed"

Answer (score 1):

First this sounds like an error with your server configuration, not with accessing the Facebook API/SDK.

Secondly, don't you need to add the call to the facebook SDK and include the `<div id="fb-root"></div>` ?

Or are you using the C# Facebook SDK?

Comment: In first example I was using asp.net facebook toolkit and get white screen, and in second example I was using plain index.html file and get that error message. I now also edited index.html to 
<div id="fb-root">
<h1> Just Plain text </h1>
</div>
And again I am getting the same error message.
This is my first time I am trying this, I have no experience with facebook apps as wel with IIS :)

Answer (score 1):

I iis you can not handle post method coming from facebook including signed_request.

So firstly reconfigure IIS allowing handle post method. Or for simple start make index.html as the default document, put inside "hello world", then process the second step.

Comment: This is almost certainly the problem; Facebook always `POST`s to the URL of your Application, sending a [`signed_request`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/signed-request/) packet with information in it.